# function handle to templated member of templated class

Tags: c++, boost-asio

How do I create a function callback to a templated function in a templated class. Here is what I have so far:

```
template <typename SocketType> 
class NettyPBSslSerializer {
    ...
    template <typename Handler>
    void async_read(google::protobuf::Message *pbmess,Handler handler ) {
            void (NettyPBSslSerializer<SocketType>::*f1)(
                    const boost::system::error_code&,std::size_t offset,google::protobuf::Message *pbmess,boost::tuple<Handler>)
                    =&NettyPBSslSerializer<SocketType>::async_read_varint <Handler> ;

            boost::asio::async_read (socket_,
                                     boost::asio::buffer(&read_buffer_.at(0), 9),
                                     boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
                                     boost::bind(f1,this,boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, pbmess,boost::make_tuple(handler) )
                                    );
    }
    template <typename Handler>
    void async_read_varint(const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t offset,google::protobuf::Message *pbmessp, boost::tuple<Handler> handler) {
    }

    ....
    SocketType socket_; 

}
```

I get the following error using  g++

```
  nettypbserializer.hpp|186| error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
  nettypbserializer.hpp|186| error: expected primary-expression before ';' token
```

line 186 is

```
=&NettyPBSslSerializer<SocketType>::async_read_varint <Handler> ;
```

Comment: I got it to compile by removing the template specifiers so line 186 ended up being:

     =&NettyPBSslSerializer::async_read_varint ; 

I don't understand why this works though. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

You can't take a pointer to a (member) function template, since it does not exist yet. One solution would be to move the `Handler` type parameter to `NettyPBSslSerializer` (so as `NettyPBSslSerializer<SocketType, HandlerType>`) and then just bind `&NettyPBSslSerializer::async_read_varint`...

EDIT:

It's actually quite easy. You can't take a pointer to member function template, but you can build a closure, where this function template will be instantiated with the correct type and pass the result to `boost::async`. Here's a [conceptual implementation](http://ideone.com/93q7U):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace boost {
    template <typename Stream, typename Handler>
    void async_read(Stream p_Stream, Handler p_Handler)
    {
        p_Handler();
    }
}

template <typename SocketType>  
class NettyPBSslSerializer { 
    SocketType m_Socket;

        template <typename Handler> 
        void async_read_varint(Handler handler) {
                handler();
        } 
public:
        template <typename Handler> 
    void async_read(Handler handler) {
        boost::async_read(m_Socket, [&]() -> void {
            this->async_read_varint(handler);
        });
        } 

    NettyPBSslSerializer(SocketType const & p_Socket) : m_Socket(p_Socket) {}
};

void a_handler()
{
    std::cout << "a_handler called" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    NettyPBSslSerializer<int> tTmp(42); 

        tTmp.async_read(a_handler);
}
```

Comment: No, this is not acceptable, I need the Handler type defined at the member function level so that a I can use various types of functions with it.

Comment: Then there is another possibility: Explicitly specialize these member functions for the `Handler` types you will be using. Then, you can take the pointer to these specialized methods, but this is far less elegant and can get pretty clumsy. I'd really recommend to redesign such that `async_read_varint` does not need to be templated.

Comment: cool, but that is utilizing c++0x standard which my compiler doesn't support (gcc 4.1.1) . Maybe I can do this using boost::lambda

Comment: You could, but much simpler solution is to define your own functor, which does exactly the same thing. I'd write an internal copyable class/struct which captures `this` and provides a call operator with proper arguments. Initialize one localy with `this` and pass the instance to `async_read`